# R approach for iterative querying

Tags: r

This is a question of a general approach in R, I'm trying to find a way into R language but the data types and loop approaches (apply, sapply, etc) are a bit unclear to me.

What is my target:
Query data from API with parameters from a config list with multiple parameters. Return the data as aggregated data.frame.

First I want to define a list of multiple vectors (colums)

```
site         segment    id
google.com   Googleuser 123
bing.com     Binguser   456
```

How to manage such a list of value groups (row by row)? data.frames are column focused, you cant write a data.frame row by row in an R script. So the only way I found to define this initial config table is a csv, which is really an approach I try to avoid, but I can't find a way to make it more elegant.

Now I want to query my data, lets say with this function:

```
query.data <- function(site, segment, id){
  config <- define_request(site, segment, id)
  result <- query_api(config)
  return result
}
```

This will give me a data.frame as a result, this means every time I query data the same columns are used. So my result should be one big data.frame, not a list of similar data.frames.

Now sapply allows to use one parameter-list and multiple static parameters. The mapply works, but it will give me my data in some crazy output I cant handle or even understand exactly what it is.

In principle the list of data.frames is ok, the data is correct, but it feels cumbersome to me.

What core concepts of R I did not understand yet? What would be the approach?

Comment: use `rbind(df, new_row)` to build a data.frame row-by-row if you have to. A better approach might be to un-serialise the way you are thinking about `query_api()` - but there isn't enough specific detail in your question to make it clear how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lapply/sapply solution that is returning a list of dataframes with identical columns, you can easily get a single large dataframe with `do.call()`.  `do.call()` inputs each item of a list as arguments into another function, allowing you to do things such as

```
big.df <- do.call(rbind, list.of.dfs)
```

Which would append the component dataframes into a single large dataframe.

In general `do.call(rbind,something)` is a good trick to keep in your back pocket when working with R, since often the most efficient way to do something will be some kind of apply function that leaves you with a list of elements when you really want a single matrix/vector/dataframe/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is a way I already tried. The do.call gives me a data frame where each row has a label which contains the small-dataframes name. This is nothing I should bother, but it looks cumbersome. 

And I still dont know how to properly lapply my function with all three parameters in a list, not just one...

Comment: I think you need to add some more information to your question then--as far as I could tell, you had a list of dataframes containing the correct information, and wanted a single dataframe.  Is the issue that you have a matrix of inputs, and you want to feed each row into a function and store the results in a matrix?